# Rate-limiting a Worker for a Queue (e.g.: SQS)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

Every day, I will have a CRON task run which populates an SQS queue with a number of tasks which needs to be achieved. So (for example) at 9AM every morning, and empty queue will receive ~100 messages that will need to be processed.

I would like a new worker to be spun up every second until the queue is empty. If any task fails, it's put at the back of the queue to be re-run.

For example, if each task takes up to 1.5 seconds to complete:

- after 1 second, 1 worker will have started message A
- after 2 seconds, 1 worker may still be running message A and 1 worker will have started running message B
- after 100 seconds, 1 worker may still be running message XX and 1 worker will pick up message B because it failed previous
- after 101 seconds, no more workers are propagated until the next morning

Is there any way to have this type of infrastructure configured within AWS lambda?

Comment: This is an interesting use-case. Can you give us a sense for why the 1 second rate limiting would be necessary (even in broad terms)? It can be accomplished with an Executor that spawns 1 thread per second and processes exactly 1 SQS poll and then works a failed queue if not empty -- but I'm still curious as to where it would be desirable. Thanks!

Comment: We're using it to communicate with a third-party API who rate limits our use of their service with a maximum of 1 request per second.

Comment: I have the same use case: Intercom rate limits to 83 requests per 10s. The system's cron kicks off a batch job which emits onto a SQS queue and a worker eventually makes requests to Intercom

Answer (score 3):

One way, though I'm not convinced it's optimal:

A lambda that's triggered by an CloudWatch Event (say every second, or every 10 seconds, depending on your rate limit). Which polls SQS to receive (at most) N messages, it then "fans-out" to another Lambda function with each message.

---

Some pseudo code:

```
# Lambda 1 (schedule by CloudWatch Event / e.g. CRON)
def handle_cron(event, context):
    # in order to get more messages, we might have to receive several times (loop)
    for message in queue.receive_messages(MaxNumberOfMessages=10):
        # Note: the Event InvocationType so we don't want to wait for the response!
        lambda_client.invoke(FunctionName="foo", Payload=message.body, InvocationType='Event')
```

and

```
# Lambda 2 (triggered only by the invoke in Lambda 1)
def handle_message(event, context):
    # handle message
    pass
```

Comment: +1. I actually like this design. It is much better than adjusting the visibility of each message when you reach an API limit.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me you would be better of publishing you messages to SNS, instead of SQS and then have your lambda functions subscribe to the SNS topic.

Let Lambda worry about how many 'instances' it needs to spinup in response to the load.

Here is one blog post on this method, but google may help you find one that is closer to your actual use case.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/invoking-aws-lambda-functions-via-amazon-sns/

Comment: Invoking isn't the issue for me at the moment, it's the rate limiting that's the problem. Any suggestions on that aspect?

Comment: Can you explain why you need to rate-limit? That answer may lead to a better answer.

Comment: Basically want to be able to send messages to an API that has an unreasonable rate limit

Comment: Isn't SNS immediate? If you add 100k messages it's going to swamp lambda, if you add 100k to SQS you can poll at some the rate-limited rate (e.g. 1000 per minute).

Comment: I suppose, but the OP was proposing ~100 messages in the queue, not a 100,000 messages. A lot of systems will fall down when you multiply the load by 1000x, and it doesn't always make sense to design for a scale that is not reasonably expected to ever happen.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just have a Lambda function that starts polling sqs at 9am, getting one message at a time and sleeping for a second between each message? Dead letter queues can handle retries. Stop execution after not receiving a message from SQS after x seconds.

It is a unique case where you don't actually want parallel processing.

Comment: I guess you could also have N Cloudwatch events all with the same CRON... to limit to N a second, when you say "Stop execution" do you mean turn off the event(s)?

Comment: What I mean is have a lambda function that polls SQS queue. After it gets a message it should process it then sleep for a second. Then poll for another message. If you poll for messages and don't receieve any for x seconds, halt execution of the lambda function until the next cron.

Comment: The issue that concerns me with this suggestion is that you pay for lambdas for how long they execute - any time you add a sleep to a lambda, you're wasting money

Comment: This is a very old post, in any case you can now directly connect Lambda to SQS so you wouldn't need to do what I had suggested. OP would only need to tweak the queue settings to limit parallel processing.